# Ruby regex extract words between { | | }

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I get the individual words contained within `{}` out of the text

```
an example of the text {Creating|Making|Producing} blah blah blah
```

I have got this far with my limited regex knowledge

```
text.scan(/{([^}]*)}/)
```

This just gives me `{Creating|Making|Producing}` but I want `Creating` `Making` `Producing`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split) the found match.

```
text.scan(/{([^}]*)}/)[0][0].split('|')
```

---

An easier regex could be:

```
text.scan(/{(.*?)}/)
```

Explanation:

- `{` - a `{` character
- `.*?}` - anything (`.*`) until the first (`?`) `}` character is encountered

Comment: would this work if the text contained just two words? {Creating|Making}

Comment: @MaxRose-Collins, it would work even if it only contained one. `split` splits by the separator. If there is none, there is nothing to split. If there is one or more, it will split wherever it finds it.

Comment: If the string might contain more than one `{..|..|..}`, you could change what you have slightly: `"now is {the|time|for} all {good|Rubyists} to..."..scan(/{([^}]*)}/).flatten(1).map { |s| s.split('|') } => [["the", "time", "for"], ["good", "Rubyists"]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another one :

```
s = 'an example of the text {Creating|Making|Producing} blah blah blah'
s.scan(/(?<=[|{])[A-Za-z]+(?=[}|])/)
# => ["Creating", "Making", "Producing"]
```

`(?<=pat) :`

> *Positive lookbehind assertion:* ensures that the preceding characters match pat, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text

`(?=pat) :`

> *Positive lookahead assertion:* ensures that the following characters match pat, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text

Look in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/fBhKMO5vsa) also.

**Update** As per the comment of *@Mike Campbell* .

```
s = 'an example of the text {Creating|Making|Producing} blah {foo} blah |bla|'
s.scan(/(?<={)[a-z|]+(?=})/i).flat_map { |m| m.split("|") }
# => ["Creating", "Making", "Producing", "foo"]
```

Again see the [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/l37Z3uW0By).

Comment: This is good, but it will also  select words outside of `{` and `}` if you surround them with `|`, or a combination of `{`, `}` and `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regular expression you could simply skip the first and last characters.

```
str = "{Creating|Making|Producing}"
str[1..-2].split('|')
=> ["Creating", "Making", "Producing"]
```

Comment: But you first have to strip `str` from the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'an example of the text {Creating|Making|Producing} blah blah blah'

s.scan(/(?<={).*(?=})/).map{|i| i.split("|") }.flatten  
# => ["Creating", "Making", "Producing"]

s.scan(/(?<={).*(?=})/).first.split("|")    
# => ["Creating", "Making", "Producing"]
```